# how to display Open xml representation of Word Documents Paragraphs into Rich text box or dsoframer using C#.net4.0 Windows form Application?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, ms-word, openxml-sdk, dsoframer

I have Word document paragraphs in an Open Xml representation(Generated by Open xml - sdk2.0).Now i want to display that Open xml representation based paragraphs in the Rich Text box or DsoFramer(anything inside the application) without changing the original style that are contained in the Orginal Word documents.How i do it?

**For Example,Open xml representation of Word Paragraph:**

```
<w:document>
<w:body>

<w:p w:rsidR="00B4789C" w:rsidRDefault="00B74039" w:rsidP="008F51E0" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">

<w:pPr>
<w:pStyle w:val="Heading1" />
    </w:pPr>

<w:proofErr w:type="gramStart" />

<w:r>
<w:t>5.</w:t>
</w:r>

<w:r w:rsidR="00B4789C" w:rsidRPr="007B7F81">
<w:t>DISPUTE</w:t>
</w:r>

<w:proofErr w:type="gramEnd" />
<w:r w:rsidR="00B4789C" w:rsidRPr="007B7F81">
<w:t xml:space="preserve"> AND SETTLEMENT, APPLICABLE LAW AND JURISDICTION</w:t>
</w:r>

</w:p>

<w:sectPr w:rsidR="003457CF" w:rsidRPr="00417420" w:rsidSect="003457CF"><w:pgSz w:w="12240" w:h="15840"/>
<w:pgMar w:top="1440" w:right="1800" w:bottom="1440" w:left="1800" w:header="720" w:footer="720" w:gutter="0"/>
<w:cols w:space="720"/><w:docGrid w:linePitch="360"/></w:sectPr>

</w:body>
</w:document>
```

Please Guide me Get out of this issue...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save the provided content to a temp file, then load it on the DSOFramer control. DSOFramer control provides an easy way to display office documents. There exists plenty of working with this control on the web.